# “To enable him to escape” vs. “to enable him escape”

Tags: grammaticality, grammar, prepositions, bare-infinitive, particles

I have been coming across this kind of sentence more and more:

> She gave him a key to enable him *to* escape capture.
>   She gave him a key to enable him escape capture.

Which sentence is correct? My understanding is that the preposition should be repeated as both *enable* and *escape* are verbs.

Comment: It depends on what verb is used; with *enable* as in your example above, I would say the "to" is required. If you use "help" instead, I would say that it is not. I don't know off the top of my head why this is, but it may have something to do theta roles.

Answer (score 11):

"To" isn't a preposition here, it's part of the verb.  Sentences like this generally use the *[full infinitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive#Full)* (or *to- infinitive*) to introduce the subordinate clause.  Like I just did there.

> She enabled him to escape capture.
>   She helped him to choose a new wardrobe.
>   She told him to go away.

*Help* turns out to be able to use a bare infinitive instead:

> She helped him choose a new wardrobe.

but not

> She enabled him escape capture.

With some verbs, you *must* use the bare infinitive.  Mostly these are verbs concerning perception or permission; unfortunately you just have to know which ones are which.

> She saw him run away.
>   She let him go.

but

> She allowed him to go.
>   She observed him to run away. *(This particular one is very unusual, and I wouldn't use it if I didn't have to!)*

Comment: +1, and that's pretty much the story. I only add that *She observed him to run away* would be understood as *She observed him [in order] to run away*, i.e. that her observation was a necessary prerequisite to her having the ability to run away.

Comment: There is a list of different verbs that catenate, the grammatical form(/s) they require, and whether or not the subject governs both verbs semantically at http://courses.washington.edu/englhtml/engl371/catenatives.html .

Answer (score -1):

Does this seem OK? Or is the second 'to' redundant?  Thanks a lot.

> Management will provide substantial levels of support, such as
>   resources and training, to enable the museum staff to provide a
>   quality guiding service.

Comment: Some might ask themselves: is this an answer or a question? Suggest edit to make it more clear that you're being rhetorical (if that is indeed what you're doing)